# why kong oauth2 does not block the request even I add oauth2 plugin for the service

Tags: oauth-2.0, kong, kong-plugin, kong-ingress

I followed the steps in https://tech.aufomm.com/how-to-use-kong-oauth2-plugin/, but the service is still able to access even the oauth2 plugin is added for the service.

I am not sure if it the deployment issue. below is the deployment details:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "18"
    kuma.io/gateway: enabled
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: kong-ic
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: kong-ic
    traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeInboundPorts: ""
  creationTimestamp: "2023-04-12T08:55:56Z"
  generation: 18
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: app
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kong-ic
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kong
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.5"
    helm.sh/chart: kong-2.4.0
    helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/name: kong-ic
    helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/namespace: flux-system
    product: platform
  name: kong-ic-kong
  namespace: kong-ic
  resourceVersion: "1072957568"
  uid: 8f10abb5-d037-493c-b449-778c264c1c17
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: app
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: kong-ic
      app.kubernetes.io/name: kong
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: "2023-04-27T11:01:45+08:00"
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: app
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: kong-ic
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/name: kong
        app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.5"
        helm.sh/chart: kong-2.4.0
        product: platform
    spec:
      automountServiceAccountToken: true
      containers:
      - args:
        - /kong-ingress-controller
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: CONTROLLER_ELECTION_ID
          value: kong-ingress-controller-leader-kong
        - name: CONTROLLER_INGRESS_CLASS
          value: kong
        - name: CONTROLLER_KONG_ADMIN_TLS_SKIP_VERIFY
          value: "true"
        - name: CONTROLLER_KONG_ADMIN_URL
          value: https://localhost:8444
        - name: CONTROLLER_PUBLISH_SERVICE
          value: kong-ic/kong-ic-kong-proxy
        image: kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller:2.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        name: ingress-controller
        ports:
        - containerPort: 10255
          name: cmetrics
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 256Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 50m
            memory: 128Mi
        securityContext: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      - env:
        - name: KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG
          value: /dev/stdout
        - name: KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG
          value: /dev/stderr
        - name: KONG_ADMIN_GUI_ACCESS_LOG
          value: /dev/stdout
        - name: KONG_ADMIN_GUI_ERROR_LOG
          value: /dev/stderr
        - name: KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN
          value: 0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 http2 ssl
        - name: KONG_CLUSTER_LISTEN
          value: "off"
        - name: KONG_DATABASE
          value: postgres
        - name: KONG_PG_HOST
          value: test.postgres.database.azure.com
        - name: KONG_PG_PORT
          value: "5432"
        - name: KONG_PG_USER
          value: admin@host
        - name: KONG_PG_PASSWORD
          value: mypassword
        - name: KONG_PG_DATABASE
          value: kong
        - name: KONG_PG_SSL
          value: "on"
        - name: KONG_PG_SSL_VERIFY
          value: "off"
        - name: KONG_KIC
          value: "on"
        - name: KONG_LUA_PACKAGE_PATH
          value: /opt/?.lua;/opt/?/init.lua;;
        - name: KONG_NGINX_WORKER_PROCESSES
          value: "2"
        - name: KONG_PLUGINS
          value: bundled
        - name: KONG_PORTAL_API_ACCESS_LOG
          value: /dev/stdout
        - name: KONG_PORTAL_API_ERROR_LOG
          value: /dev/stderr
        - name: KONG_PORT_MAPS
          value: 80:8000, 443:8443
        - name: KONG_PREFIX
          value: /kong_prefix/
        - name: KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG
          value: /dev/stdout
        - name: KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG
          value: /dev/stderr
        - name: KONG_PROXY_LISTEN
          value: 0.0.0.0:8000, 0.0.0.0:8443 http2 ssl
        - name: KONG_STATUS_LISTEN
          value: 0.0.0.0:8100
        - name: KONG_STREAM_LISTEN
          value: "off"
        - name: KONG_NGINX_DAEMON
          value: "off"
        image: kong:2.5
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command:
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - /bin/sleep 15 && kong quit
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /status
            port: status
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        name: proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8001
          name: admin
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8444
          name: admin-tls
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8000
          name: proxy
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8443
          name: proxy-tls
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8100
          name: status
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /status
            port: status
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 256Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 256Mi
        securityContext: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /kong_prefix/
          name: kong-ic-kong-prefix-dir
        - mountPath: /tmp
          name: kong-ic-kong-tmp
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      serviceAccount: kong-ic-kong
      serviceAccountName: kong-ic-kong
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: kong-ic-kong-prefix-dir
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: kong-ic-kong-tmp
```

curl -X GET http://kong:8000/demo should return 401, but now it returns 200.